# display a table of employees with delete button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I would like to know why my following code piece displays nothing in the browser (http://localhost/display.php). I would like to generate a template for my table to display all employees in my database (id, firstname, lastname) and use HTTP verb DELETE via jquery ajax method to delete a user if I click the delete button on the display table.

Here is my display.php

```
<table id="employees" border="1">
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>    
    $document.ready(function()
    {
    var $employees = $("#employees");
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        contentType: "json",
        success: function(data){            

        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            var $row = $("#templates").find(".row-template").clone();
            $row.find(".firstName").html(item.FirstName);
            $row.find(".lastName").html(item.LastName);
            $row.find(".delete").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "delaction.php" + item.Id,
                type: "DELETE",
                success: function()
            {
                    $row.remove();
                }
            });
            });
        $employees.append($row);
        });
      }
    });
});

</script>

<div id="templates" style="display: none">        
    <table>            
    <tr class="row-template">                
        <td class="firstName" style="width: 100px;"></td>
        <td class="lastName" style="width: 100px;"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="X" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>     
</div>
```

and my delete.php looks like this

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_ROOT','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_NAME','employees');

$conn=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_ROOT,DB_PASS) or die("Unable to connect to your selected db.Error ".mysqli_error());
if(null!=$conn)
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn,DB_NAME);
    $query=("SELECT * FROM empl");
    $result=mysqli_query($query);
    foreach($result as $res)
    {

    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It displays nothing because your response to the AJAX request does not contain any data. Read up on `mysqli` usage (`mysqli_fetch_assoc`) and `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

What's in 'delaction.php'?

Anyway, to pass itemId to delaction.php with the item to delete, change:

```
url: "delaction.php" + item.Id,
```

to:

```
url: "delaction.php?itemId=" + item.Id,
```

Comment: Thanks, but why my display.php displays nothing ?